# Python Bokeh rollover color

Tags: python, bokeh

I use Python comprehensive list to display several charts (under bokeh env) and use HoverTool to display some data values.

```
[p.line(x='newindex', y='count', source=result.loc[result.index.year == i],\
color=next(colors),line_width=4,legend_label=str(i)) for i in unique_sorted_date]
hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips='Date: @oldindex <br>  deces: @count')
p.add_tools(hover_tool)
```

I would like to highlight the line where I want to retrieve information (from tooltips).
For instance, the selected line will be red and the others one greys.
Is there an easy way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option highlights the curve hover_line_color="red"